# Draw a dashed line between two UIButtons using getting dynamically positions of Frame

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

Hi I want to draw dashed line from one UIButton to another button.

I have taken this code to draw line between to points:

```
func addDashedLine(fromPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint) {
    let line = CAShapeLayer()
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.moveToPoint(start)
    linePath.addLineToPoint(end)
    line.path = linePath.CGPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    line.lineWidth = 1
   //line.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
    line.lineDashPattern = [8, 8]
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)
}
```

To take startPoint and Endpoint I am using button.center() for both button. But Line is not drawing from center to center. It's drawing outside of UIButton. I have used Autolayout for button, and set constraints from superview using multiplier.

Please suggest me how to do this.?

Comment: Are your buttons inside `self.view` or maybe in other containing subviews? In this case their `center` point represents their position inside those subviews. You might want to convert that point to main view coordinates like this: `self.view.convertPoint(button.center, fromView: buttonContainerView)`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
let startPoint = CGPoint(x: button1.frame.origin.x + button1.frame.size.width, y: button1.frame.origin.y + (button1.frame.size.height/2.0))
let endPoint = CGPoint(x: button2.frame.origin.x, y: button2.frame.origin.y + (button2.frame.size.height / 2.0))
addDashedLine(fromPoint start:stratrPoint, toPoint end:endPoint)
```

**EDIT**

But maybe if you are using AutoLayout, if you are using a StackView this should not work